# I removed Bluez, but now cannot get back to GUI

Tags: centos, bluetooth, gui, delete, bluez

Bluetooth has always been a problem.

In the past, I tinkered with a few things in the command line and got it to work.  then it stopped again, so I just left it alone.

Well, it turns out I wanted to try something with Bluetooth again, so I thought if I plugged those commands in, it would work again.  At least temporarily.

But I went in and tried everything I could find about it on the net, and nothing worked.

So the last resort would be to remove 'bluez' right?  At least according to what I read, removing and re-installing would be no problem and fix it...

Well, when I plugged in the remove bluez command, it went to a black screen with a blinking _ at the top left hand corner of the screen.
I waited a while, but nothing happened.

So I rebooted the system and now it goes to a command line text interface, and I definitely do not want this.

I have tried pretty much everything that I could find to get it to boot normally into the GUI, but nothing seems to work.  I really didn't think that this process would cause so much trouble for me...

OK, so basically I really could care less about using the Bluetooth because it never worked well anyways.
All I want is to be able to go back to where I was before...doing point and click computer stuff!

Please help!!!

Oh yeah, CentOS 8